# Yii CActiveForm client and ajax validation behavior

Tags: php, validation, yii, active-form

How does client validation trigger? as this code:

```
<? $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',array(
'id' => 'user-register',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>true, 
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    'afterValidate' => "js: function(form, data, hasError) {
        console.log(data);
        return false;
    }"
)));
?>

<?= $form->errorSummary($user); ?>

<?= $form->textField($user, 'email'); ?>
<?= $form->error($user,'email'); ?>
<? $this->endWidget() ?>
```

works fine (shows error for email field as described in User model both in errorSummary() and error() methods, but then I remove

```
<?= $form->error($user,'email'); ?>
```

Client validation doesn't trigger and form is submited

Same behavior goes for ajax validation

Comment: @SamuelLiew, Why aren't they supposed to be allowed here? If that's so then there would be no need for the `yii` tag, `rails` tag or `codeigniter` tag

Comment: @ThorpeObazee I never said Yii questions were off-topic. This question is simply too broad for asking how the Yii framework works. If you think it isn't, then answer it (I'll see how you try). Also, this question is unclear as there is no specific problem, and OP did not specify exactly what what he needs to accomplish. If you have a problem, bring it up on [meta].

Comment: @SamuelLiew, I agree. Too much information perhaps for a `question`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you have to put in the controller:

```
$this->performAjaxValidation($model);
```

just before:

```
if (isset($_POST['User']))
```

Then, find the function **performAjaxValidation** (in the same controller)and change the default string to **user-register**, like that:

```
protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
{
    if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'user-register')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
```